# ipv6 address of default LAN gateway

Tags: netplan, ipv6

19.04

I'm setting up some IPV6 static addressing using netplan and want to put the ipv6 gateway.

```
 wifis:
   wlp3s0:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [10.0.0.120/24,"fe00::120/64"]
     gateway4: 10.0.0.1
     gateway6: fe00::1
```

I take the `gateway6` address from the `/etc/hosts` entry for `ip6-localnet`  which is given as `fe00::0` and the fact that the ipv4 gateway IP is 10.0.0.1

This configuration applies without errors or warnings and the host is accessible via ssh through its ipv6 address.

But though `ping 10.0.0.1` gets a response  `ping6 fe00::1` does not. (Both ping and ping6 get responses from ..110)

So I have an error here somewhere.

Comment: How do you know that your local router is at fe00::1? fe00::/9 appears to be reserved. fe80::/9 is link local scope.

Comment: @vidarlo I was just guessing from the `/etc/hosts` and the gateway ipv4 address. Bad guess, I guess. So  : the netplan entry should be `gateway6: fe80::1`? That doesn't work either.

Comment: No. The entry should be the actual gateway IP. You can find that through [RA's](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6_basic/configuration/xe-3s/ip6b-xe-3s-book/ip6-neighb-disc-xe.html#GUID-1C16B07D-4464-4506-9E0B-DA6AA7743E83) or check what the *actual* IP of the gateway is. The normal thing with IPv6 would be to use DHCPv6 or SLAAC with public IP's on the host, and a router in the FE80::/9 subnet.

Comment: Don't use manual IPv6 addressing if you can avoid it. It is too error-prone. Just enable DHCPv6 if your ISP provides IPv6, and forget about it.

Comment: fe00 is definitely not your gateway.  "Local" here means "local to your host".

Comment: @MichaelHampton By 'error-prone' do you mean 'difficult to configure' or do you mean 'unreliable'?

Comment: @slagasek How strange. I am successfully communicating with LAN hosts given static IPs in the netplan config  as `fe00::n` So are those connections through some aliasing perhaps? I'm not really addressing that ipv6 IP but the ipv4 IP associated with that string?

Comment: Difficult to configure, difficult to maintain, and unreliable hit all the high points. As you're using reserved space, instead of whatever might actually be appropriate, there's no way to know whether Linux will continue to accept your current configuration in the future.